# Geoserver - raster layer title in getfeatureinfo template

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo, template

Relatively new to GeoServer, moving from MapServer and I'm trying to generate a GetFeatureInfo template for a raster layer.

I'm trying to pull in the layer title via "${feature.type.title}", which seems to work fine for vector layers, however, when attempting this with the (multiband) raster layer, it seems to return "Layer: " followed by the layer name.

Is there any way to access the title for this raster layer?